# Multiplicacion con elementos de una estructura

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se realiza la operacion de (b es igual a la d de la imagen) b[i] = (((puntos_recta[i].p.x) * (vector_rectas[i].m)) + puntos_recta[i].p.y), solo guarda en b el valor del punto y, no puedo aplicar la formula de b = y + mx.

Al momento de compilar el vector b[] solo captura el valor de y, sin embargo, si las operaciones son sumas si lo realiza.
b[i] = (((puntos_recta[i].p.x) + (vector_rectas[i].m)) + puntos_recta[i].p.y

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>

     struct punto{
           double x;
           double y;
     };
     struct recta{
           struct punto p; 
           double m;    
     };

     struct recta rectas[5];

     int main(){
          double b[5];
          int i,j;
          for (i=0; i<=4; i++){
                printf("Defina el punto %i ",i+1);
                printf("\n");
                scanf("%d",&rectas[i].p.x);
                scanf("%d",&rectas[i].p.y);
                printf("Defina la pendiente %i\n",i+1);
                scanf("%d",&rectas[i].m);

                printf("\n");




                b[i] = rectas[i].p.y + (rectas[i].p.x * rectas[i].m);

                printf("%d",b[i]);

                printf("\n");
       }



                 return 0;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia en los llamados a

```
scanf %d
```

por

```
%lf
```

y en el

```
printf %d
```

por

```
%f
```